# Using @Transactional in Micronaut without using Hibernate

Tags: jdbc, micronaut

Micronaut has support for JDBC, and the guide states that @Transactional from micronaut-spring can be used for AOP style transaction handling. I can't get this to work, when using @Transaction with a plain datasource, I get an exception that no TransactionManager is in place.

Do anyone know if I can use plain JDBC with micronaut with @Transactional support?

Comment: You need a TransactionManager in order to use a declarative transaction management. Read [https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.x/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#spring-data-tier]

Comment: i need this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is the DataSource needs to be wrapped in a TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy in order to perform @Transaction

U can try to add smth like this

```
compile "io.micronaut:spring"
runtime "org.springframework:spring-jdbc"
```

Comment: I tried adding above 2 dependencies into micronaut Gradle file but its showing error.